# Problems in bitwise shifting with Codewarrior

Tags: bit-manipulation, shift, codewarrior

I'm working in Codewarrior and trying to perform a bitwise shift to the left (>>) to a "char-casted" int variable, i.e.:

```
int checksum=0x017b;

char checksum_H=(char) checksum >>8; //higher part of checksum
char checksum_L=(char) checksum;     //lower part of checksum
```

The thing is, I can actually get the correct value for `checksum_L`, but for `checksum_H` I get 0x00.... and only when I try to perform the shift with ">" instead of ">>" do I get the correct result of 0x01...

Does anyone of you have any idea why this could be happening?

Answer (score 0):

You're being bitten by operator precedence. In your expression:

```
char checksum_H=(char) checksum >>8;
```

you are first casting `checksum` to `char`, and thereby losing all but the low order byte, after which you shift right by 8 bits, thereby clearing the remaining 8 bits that you still have, and hence returning 0.

So it needs to be:

```
char checksum_H = (char)(checksum >> 8);
```

in order to carry out the shift first, and then the cast.